# How to enable free text for ComboBox in UWP

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have added a ComboBox in a UWP app that I am working on for Windows 10 and I am not able to make it so that users can type in free text if the value they need on it doesn't match any of the values available to select.

How can I do this?

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx), the description for `ComboBox.IsEditable` is:

> Gets or sets a value that enables or disables editing of the text in
>   text box of the ComboBox.

Which seems to be what is needed. However, this seems to be only for WPF.

It does not seem to have a settable `IsEditable` property on XAML:

[image: IsEditable in XAML]

On the code behind, when I try to access this property, it shows that the property only has `get` and that it always returns `false`:

[image: IsEditable in code behind]

Please let me know how I could make this possible. Thank you!

Comment: @Naruto Niichan, something which I didn't include in my answer, was the fact that you can not set or modify the property IsEditable in UWP. Only in WPF.

Comment: @AndréB yup. i figured that and updated the question. thank you for the answer. I am still debating what what is the best way to proceed. thanks again!

Comment: You want to make sure you add 'uwp' to your searches for controls as the link you have is to the WPF doc.

The UWP doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox)

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT thanks. good catch. any plans to implement this on UWP?

Comment: @slayernoah best way to make that happen is to upvote this User Voice item for it: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18505435-editable-combo-box

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT thanks! I did that today morning. That still has only 65 votes so I guess it has a long way to go :(

Comment: @slayernoah It's also in the backlog for the toolkit too which looks at the UserVoice numbers also: https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/845

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT thank you. could you also look into my other uwp question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954818/populate-combobox-items-and-selectedvalue-in-a-combobox-that-is-within-a-gridvie

Answer (score 5):

I have not tried yet but here is an implementation of ComboBox with editable textbox on UWP.

[ComboBox with Editable Textbox](https://liftcodeplay.com/2016/02/18/combobox-with-editable-textbox/)

And, basically, Autosuggest option is totally different one from editable ComboBox - Autosuggest just suggest the candidate from the current item list, but not accept to entering the new one. To implement it, you need to implement the custom user control like the above guy.

**Added Oct 2018** - From Windows 10 October 2018 Update, ComboBox now have the IsEditable property. Wao! Not well-documented yet but this blog post is helpful.

[XAML ComboBox IsEditable and Text Properties](https://reflectionit.nl/blog/2018/xaml-combobox-iseditable-and-text-properties)

Answer (score 0):

If your UWP app is running on a device with at least the `Anniversary Update`, version and you have set the *minimum platform version* of the UWP project to at least the `Anniversary Update` (version 1607), you will be able to utilize the Dependency Property `IsTextSearchEnabled`, which by being set to *True* will allow you to jump to a value by typing.

The problem is that you should instantiate this in code-behind rather than in XAML, by utilizing the `ApiInformation` Class, preventing the situation where your app is being run on an older Windows 10 version which doesn't recognize this dependency property. [Details Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ComboBox_IsTextSearchEnabled)

If the minimum targeted version of your app is Creators Update version, you can also perform this run-time decisions on XAML based on the API present with .[Conditional Xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml)

Define a custom namespace, which corresponds to a conditional method, where you query whether the 3th version of the UniversalApiContract is present (minimum required for this dependency property).

```
xmlns:contract3Present="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?IsApiContractPresent(Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,3)"
```

Then in your ComboBox, you could do the following:

```
<ComboBox contract3Present:IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
```

This dependency property would be only set if the Device running the application has the the required operating system version!

---

Another solution completely different from what was discussed would be a `Custom Control` where you could extend the `ComboBox` logic, implementing text search for it. You could listen to key presses while the `ComboBox` has received focus, and you could order to collection based on the keys pressed.

Comment: The `IsTextSearchEnabled` just lets keypresses select items, it doesn't let the user type their own value as was asked.