# Populate ComboBox items and SelectedValue in a ComboBox that is within a GridView DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am developing a Windows 10 Universal App and I have trouble getting items to populate in a ComboBox (both ComboBox items and SelectedValue) that is within a GridView DataTemplate. I don't seem to be able to find a way to do this.

**Here are the details:**

I have an object (`UserData`) that can contain multiple instances of another object (`List<VisitedCity>`). On the XAML page, the multiple instances of `VisitedCity` are shown on a vertical GridView.

Each instance of `VisitedCity` can contain the `CityName` and `VisitedDate`. On the XAML page, the CityName is to be shown on a ComboBox and the visited date on a Date on a DatePicker inside each GridViewItem.

**What doesn't work:**

The ComboBox showing the selected city name of each VisitedCity needs to have it's list of items on it loaded from a `List<string>` variable (so that the user can change it) and the ComboBox SelectedValue needs to be loaded from the curretUserData object's `VisitedCities` property (CityName property).

**I an trying to do this using `x:Bind` on the XAML in order to minimize the code behind.**

I have included all my code from the sample app I did to troubleshoot this and I have also indicated the line of code on the XAML that I am having issues with.

Please note, this is highly simplified part of a larger app with VisistedCities as an example so that the problem can be demonstrated better. Thank you for all your help and input!

Here is my class file:

```
namespace mySampleApp
{
    class UserData
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public List<VisitedCity> VisitedCities { get; set; }
    }

    class VisitedCity
    {
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public DateTime VisitedDate { get; set; }

    }

    class CityNameManager
    {
        public static List<string> GetListOfCitiesFromServer()
        {
            List<string> listOfCities = new List<string>();

            //code will be here to get the latest list from the server. for now we will manually return a list

            listOfCities.Add("City1");
            listOfCities.Add("City2");
            listOfCities.Add("City3");
            listOfCities.Add("City4");
            listOfCities.Add("City5");

            return listOfCities;

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="mySampleApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:mySampleApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Grid.Row="0" Header="Enter Your Name" Text="{x:Bind curretUserData.FullName}"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="label1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="Please select all cities you have visited during the last 5 years. For each city please enter the data visited. If you visited a city multiple times, please have multiple entries for each time indicating the date visited each time." />

        <TextBlock x:Name="label2" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="Press the + button to add rows as needed. " />

        <Button x:Name="myButton" Grid.Row="3" Content="+" Click="myButton_Click" />

        <GridView x:Name="myGridView" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{x:Bind curretUserData.VisitedCities}">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:VisitedCity">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- This is the line of code which has issues-->
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="myTemplateComboBox"  ItemsSource="{local:CityList ??? }" SelectedValue="{x:Bind CityName ??? }" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />

                        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="myTemplateDatePicker" Date="{x:Bind VisitedDate }" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
namespace mySampleApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        //variables to use in XAML x:Bind
        private UserData curretUserData = new UserData();
        private List<string> CityList = new List<string>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            //get latest list of cities from the server
            CityList = CityNameManager.GetListOfCitiesFromServer();

            //add sample data to show on the page for demo
            curretUserData.FullName = "Sample User";
            List<VisitedCity> sampleUserVisitedCities = new List<VisitedCity>();
            sampleUserVisitedCities.Add(new VisitedCity {CityName = "City1", VisitedDate=DateTime.Parse("2/2/2016") });
            sampleUserVisitedCities.Add(new VisitedCity {CityName = "City2", VisitedDate = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2015") });
            curretUserData.VisitedCities = sampleUserVisitedCities;

            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //add a new row
            GridViewItem gridViewItem = new GridViewItem();
            gridViewItem.ContentTemplate = myGridView.ItemTemplate;
            myGridView.Items.Add(gridViewItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your binding expression to grab from the parent page.  x:Bind will only use the local DataContext, which in this case is the templated item.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="myTemplateComboBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=CityList }" SelectedValue="{x:Bind CityName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
```

In this case, I make the CityList a public property and then named the Page so that we could grab it using `ElementName`.

You also need to enable `TwoWay` Binding so that you can get the values set back to your data model after the user makes a change.

If you use an Observable collection instead of a List, then you can add to your GridView rows by modifying your data model.  I was hitting an exception otherwise.

I also swapped out the initial username for PlaceholderText so that the user doesn't have to erase the sample name in order to type theirs.

Full code

```
<Page
    x:Class="SOCityGridView.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SOCityGridView"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="MyPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Grid.Row="0" Header="Enter Your Name" Text="{x:Bind currentUserData.FullName}" PlaceholderText="Sample User"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="label1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="Please select all cities you have visited during the last 5 years. For each city please enter the data visited. If you visited a city multiple times, please have multiple entries for each time indicating the date visited each time." />

        <TextBlock x:Name="label2" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="Press the + button to add rows as needed. " />

        <Button x:Name="myButton" Grid.Row="3" Content="+" Click="myButton_Click" />

        <GridView x:Name="myGridView" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{x:Bind currentUserData.VisitedCities}">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:VisitedCity">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- This is the line of code which has issues-->
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="myTemplateComboBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=CityList }" SelectedValue="{x:Bind CityName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />

                        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="myTemplateDatePicker" Date="{x:Bind VisitedDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace SOCityGridView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        //variables to use in XAML x:Bind
        private UserData currentUserData = new UserData();
        public List<string> CityList { get; set; } = new List<string>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            //get latest list of cities from the server
            CityList = CityNameManager.GetListOfCitiesFromServer();

            //add sample data to show on the page for demo
            List<VisitedCity> sampleUserVisitedCities = new List<VisitedCity>();
            sampleUserVisitedCities.Add(new VisitedCity { CityName = "City1", VisitedDate = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2016") });
            sampleUserVisitedCities.Add(new VisitedCity { CityName = "City2", VisitedDate = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2015") });
            currentUserData.VisitedCities = new ObservableCollection<VisitedCity>(sampleUserVisitedCities);

            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentUserData.VisitedCities.Add(new VisitedCity { CityName = "City1", VisitedDate = DateTime.Now });
        }
    }

    public class UserData
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<VisitedCity> VisitedCities { get; set; }
    }

    public class VisitedCity
    {
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset VisitedDate { get; set; }

    }

    public class CityNameManager
    {
        public static List<string> GetListOfCitiesFromServer()
        {
            List<string> listOfCities = new List<string>();

            //code will be here to get the latest list from the server. for now we will manually return a list

            listOfCities.Add("City1");
            listOfCities.Add("City2");
            listOfCities.Add("City3");
            listOfCities.Add("City4");
            listOfCities.Add("City5");

            return listOfCities;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!! that worked like a charm! Does this mean that there is no way we could use the new x:Bind to populate the combobox within the datatemplate from a property of the parent element?

Comment: Correct, when [x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) is in the data template it uses the data type as the data context, so you can't get outside of the template without using the regular binding.

x:Bind should certainly be preferred, but can't be utilized in all cases.

Comment: thanks! just wanted to make sure I was using the best approach. thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem.  There's a few different options depending on the scenario like `TemplateBinding` and using RelativeSource, but it all depends on if you're in your main page, a data template or a style.

Comment: thanks! could you also take a look at this other issue i am having?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113978

Comment: could you take a look at this issue that i am having? thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161273/how-to-easily-allow-users-to-update-styles-used-be-elements-in-xaml-uwp