# How to easily allow users to update Styles used be elements in XAML (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

This is for a Windows 10 UWP. I need to allow users to update values on Styles that are associated with elements used throughout the application (i.e allow users to change the font size of various textblocks, background color stackpanels etc.) .

I currently have all my Styles in a separately file.

My `App.xaml` is as below:

```
<Application
    x:Class="MyTestApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

My `Styles.xaml` (partial) is as below:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="using:MyTestApp.Views"
    xmlns:x1="using:System">

    <Style x:Key="HeaderTextBlocks" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,4,0,0"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RegularTextBlocks" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I refer to these styles on controls throughout the application using like this:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlocks}" />
```

I have created a Settings page (settings.xaml) which has textboxes for the users to update various style settings.

**But I am not sure how I could bind these to the settings on the various styles on the styles.xaml file so that the styles are updated and the controls referring to the styles are updated when the user changes the value.**

```
<TextBox Header="Font Size of Header TextBlocks" Text="{x:Bind HeaderTextBlocks.FontSize ???, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Header="Font Size of Regular TextBlocks" Text="{x:Bind RegularTextBlocks.FontSize???, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I am trying to do this with minimal (or no code behind) as possible.

Comment: @TobiasTheel thanks for the reply! But I don’t see how to use DynamicResource with a Windows 10 UWP :/

Comment: Unfortunately `DynamicResource` markup extension is not available in UWP

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this kind of user-defined styling is not easily available in UWP. You can however implement a kind of styling solution using data binding.

First step is to create a class like `CustomUISettings` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has properties like `HeaderFontSize`, etc.

Now on app start create an instance of this class and add it as app resource:

```
Application.Current.Resources["CustomUISettings"] = new CustomUISettings();
```

Now you can bind to the properties in this class anywhere in your code:

```
<TextBox FontSize="{Binding HeaderFontSize, Source={StaticResource CustomUISettings}}" />
```

You must use the classic `{Binding}` markup extension, because `{x:Bind}` does not support `Source` setting.

To modify the UI settings you can just retrieve the instance anywhere and set the properties as you see fit:

```
var customUISettings = (CustomUISettings)Application.Current.Resources["CustomUISettings"];
customUISettings.HeaderFontSize = 50;
```

You must make sure that all properties in `CustomUISettings` class fire the `PropertyChanged` event. You can see how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for example [here](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.cz/2016/01/the-evolution-of-inotifypropertychanged.html).

Comment: Fwiw, x:Bind can bind to statics, so you could make CustomUISettings a setting class, if you wanted too.

Comment: True thing, I forgot about that :-) . I will update my answer with this! Thank you for the reminder!

Comment: @Johnny Westlake - but wait, I am confuesd, Binding can bind to static, but does x:Bind? x:Bind binds only to code-behind properties and fields or is there some other syntax that allows this? And futher - the problem with static class is that it cannot implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is a problem here...

Comment: If I have a static class "MyApp.Converters", you can add a namespace def (xmlns:my="using:MyApp" for example) and then you can use {x:Bind my:Converters.Invert(...)}, which also works in datatemples- in this case you could have {x:Bind my:Resources.CustomUISettings.FontSize, Mode=OneWay}, where CustomUISettings is still an instance in the static

Comment: @Johnny Westlake: That is weird, I can't get this to work on my end - I always jsut get "Invalid binding path - Property "my:Converters" can't be found on type MainPage :-O