# C# UWP dynamically change global font

Tags: c#, fonts, uwp, resources

I have created a global font resource in `App.xaml` like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <FontFamily x:Key="GlobalFontLight">Arial</FontFamily>
        <FontFamily x:Key="GlobalFont">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
        <FontFamily x:Key="GlobalFontBold">Caibri</FontFamily>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In MainPage I have added a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text" FontFamily="{StaticResource GlobalFont}" Foreground="Black"/>
<TextBlock Text="Some text 2" FontFamily="{StaticResource GlobalFontLight}" Foreground="Black"/>
<TextBlock Text="Some text 3" FontFamily="{StaticResource GlobalFontBold}" Foreground="Black"/>
```

And it is ok, `TextBlock` use my global font.

Now, I want to change that global font in Application Resources. I have tried next code:

```
Application.Current.Resources["GlobalFont"] = new FontFamily("Arial");
```

But nothing happens, `TextBlock` still use the old font. If I run this code before `InitializeComponent();` then it is working as I want, but after that no. Anyone knows what do I do wrong? How to achieve this dynamic change of font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because UWP does not support `DynamicResource` this is quite a problem. The `StaticResource` and `ThemeResource` extensions won't save you here, because they are bound only when evaluated and will not update for the already-evaluated properties when the underlying resource changes.

The first option would be to navigate back and navigate to the same page again, so that the controls get reloaded and the resources evaluated anew.

If you want something more dynamic, please check out [my answer on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49168742/732221). If you follow that solution, you can create a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` that will contain a property of type `FontFamily`, store this instance in a `StaticResource` and then use binding instead of `StaticResource` like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Font, Source={StaticResource CustomUISettings}}" />
```

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!